# How can I add text to a single nav menu item?

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm working on a theme that requires the end-user to specify the current performance season using a custom admin panel I've created, ie. "2013/2014", "2014/2015" etc., which I can retrieve using `get_option('current_season');`

On my custom nav menu I have a page titled "Season" that needs the aforementioned field inserted into it so it reads "2013/2014 Season" rather than just "Season".

The walker tutorials I have looked at only seem to show examples of adding a class to menu items but I need to add specific text to one menu item. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `wp_nav_menu_objects` filter. This seems to work, but not sure what other side-effects it may have, you'll want to test thoroughly.

```
function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items ){
    foreach( $items as $item ){
        if( 'Season' == $item->title ){
            $item->title = get_option('current_season') . ' Season';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects' );
```

Comment: I'm astonished at what a knowledge of wordpress filters can do for a person. This worked brilliantly, right out of the box. I appreciate the assist and I'll let you know if I find any side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Most of individual menu item markup generation happens in [`Walker_Nav_Menu->start_el()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.5/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L57)

The title is going through filter in this part of code:

```
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
```

So `the_title` filter should allow you to modify it. However it is somewhat challenging to implement precisely and depends on your specifics how to target it, because WP uses same filter in `get_the_title()` function for titles in general.